# Delay in getting response from web service while calling from ajax using jQuery

Tags: .net, web-services, jquery

I am calling a web service (c#)method using jQuery .And after getting result from web service I have to bind data in a html form .But problem is that while running a code  I am getting late response from web service till that time my function return null and without setting field of form.
below is my code. Here I am getting null value for v

```
function CallBGHostService(aParam) {

var v = null;
$.ajax({

    url: "http://localhost/MyService.asmx/GetBusinessGroupData",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'aBusinessGroupID':'" + aParam + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.withCredentials = true; },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function test(response) {
        v = response.d;
        alert(response.d);

    },
    error: function test(response) {
        v = response.d;
        alert(response.d);
               }
});

return (v);

}
```

Comment: Can you try changing your `data:` to `data: { aBuisnessGroupID: aParam),`?

Comment: @shaun5 I changed the data but then with this service is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Just to see what you're receiving change `dataType: "text"` in your setup and change your `success` function to `success: function(response) {alert(response);},`.  Your error function is setup incorrectly it should be: `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(errorThrown);}`.  Also you don't need to name the `success` and `error` functions.  You certainly don't need to name them the same thing!

Comment: Since result has to be in json format so we can't change datatype.Also I tried to change both success and error call back function but no luck still getting late response from web service

Comment: What do you mean by late response?